# MacOS M1 - Docker desktop Why qemu-system-aarch64 takes large amount of memory once it starts?

Tags: docker, mac-osx

I am running docker-desktop on MACOS M1 chipset, once I start my docker desktop application.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot too much amount of memory as well as CPU is being utilized.

Comment: I don't see CPU utilization in the picture but docker desktop can consume a lot of resources, even on Intel-based CPUs. Are you running any containers inside the docker? Are they perhaps amd64/x86 based images instead of native arm images?

Comment: In image, shown of excessive memory usage only and that too without any container running @juraj. Is this normal?  I also thought that If I create amd64 platform image then only the above service is taking too much resource but that is not the case.

Comment: Regarding high memory usage on macos I bookmarked this report a long time ago (I dont' remember the details): https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3377. There was a link to this document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/17ZiQC1Tp9iH320K-uqVLyiJmk4DHJ3c4zgQetJiKYQM/edit

Comment: thanks @JurajMartinka I will check

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue! Blank installation of docker with zero containers. 9.87 GB usage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the amount of memory allocated under **Settings** in Docker Desktop:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by enabling the `Virtualization Framework` in Docker settings.
[Docker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMBFl.png)